# Rest API Get with query parameters proper responses

Tags: api, rest, http-status-codes, query-string

I have implemented a Rest API with vectored ids:

```
http://example.com/api/user/1
http://example.com/api/user/2
http://example.com/api/user/1,3
http://example.com/api/user/1,2,3
```

Rest dictates that if "user/2" doesn't exist to return a 404.

Disregarding a possible solution that involve query parameters, what are the appropriate responses for the following situations?

**user/1,2 - user/1 exists and user/2 exists**
Response is a 200 with both elements returned in a set

**user/1,3 - user/1 exists and user/3 DOES NOT exist**
1? Response is 200 with the user 1 in a set?
2? Response is 404 because user/3 can't be returned?

And since we could possibly be dealing with empty sets with 1? above, does this mean
**user/3 - user/3 doesn't exist**
1? Response is 200 with an empty set?

Comment: I have noticed stack exchange's API uses the empty set scenario for some calls.

Comment: My opinion would be 404 for when the full set fails. When a partial set works, use 200 and just return the values [users] that existed. Importantly, document the behavior of the API. Sets are one of the "not covered" areas of REST so it's a judgment call on the developer's part. That said, I also find the 200 in all cases and an empty set appealing. It is a little more consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that response format is the same for single ID and several IDs (vectored IDs). It's one of REST principals: GET is a "safe method" ([nullipotent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nullipotent)) and should produce no side-effects.

For endpoints that support vectored IDs in `GET` request I usually use response format similar to [OpenSearch](http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/1.1) i.e.

`GET user/1,3` where user/1 exists and user/3 does not exist returns 200 with

```
{
  "startIndex": 0,
  "count": 1,
  "itemsPerPage": 1,
  "entry": [
    { /* user/1 */}
  ]
}
```

`GET user/3` where user/3 does not exist returns 200 with

```
{
  "startIndex": 0,
  "count": 0,
  "itemsPerPage": 0,
  "entry": []
}
```

Comment: I added a citation to the rest principle you reference that GET must adhere to.